# Error A2105 : Expected : instruction or directive Assembly

Tags: masm, directive

I'm making a simple message program using MASM. Currently I'm running DOSBOX on Windows 8 64-bit. I had a folder 8086 that contains DEBUG, BIN2HEX, EDIT, EXE2BIN, LINK, MASM, TASM and TD executable files. The MASM is different from ML commands.

Back to my question, when I tried to used `masm Hello.asm`. I got `Error A2105 : Expected : instruction or directive`. I have use some directives in my codes.

**Hello.asm**

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC
extrn ExitProcess@4 : PROC

.data
    HelloWorld db "Welcome to Assembly Language!", 0
    MsgTitle db "Our First MessageBox", 0
.code
start:

    mov eax,0
    push eax
    lea ebx , MsgTitle
    push ebx
    lea ebx, HelloWorld
    push ebx
    push eax
    call MessageBoxA@16
    push eax
    call ExitProcess@4

end start
```

I have no ideas how to create OBJ,LST,CRF from this asm. So I just skip both of them.

```
Object filenam [hello.OBJ] :
Source listing [NUL.LST]:
Cross-reference [NUL.CRF]:
hello.asm(3): error 2105 : Expected : instruction or directive
```

Comment: Which version of MASM are you using?

Comment: when masm asks you about the .obj, .lst and .crf it is to *generate* them, you do not have to provide them

Answer (score 0):

I do not know MASM but from the error message it is clear that the assembler does not consider this line

```
option casemap: none
```

as a valid instruction or directive. So you should check whether you use a correct format. Maybe you need to remove the blank after the semicolon. In any case you may simply remove it from the program that to compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction or directive `option casemap: none` is invalid in your masm version. so you should check it if you don't know why use `option casemap: none`, maybe you can delete it, and then you can compile the code correctly.